# Issue getting remaining days,hours/minutes.. to date with moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions in my app, one where I get the instance of the next weekday I choose (get me next thursday for example), then I have a function which calculates remianing days,hours,minutes and seconds.

So far I can get remaining days, but hours, minutes and seconds show as 0. This is because when the date I get for next thursday doesnt have the required timestamp format:

```
nextThursday "2022-03-24T15:11:48.580Z"

 LOG  Days:  5.999999745370371
 LOG  Hours:  0
 LOG  Minutes:  0
 LOG  Seconds:  0
```

HOW CAN I ADD HOURS AND MINUTES (00:00) to the moment timestamp I get, I think that would be the problem!

```
let nextThursday = getNextThursday();
getCountdown();

const getNextThursday = () =>
    {
        const dayINeed = 4; // for Thursday
        const today = moment().isoWeekday();

        // if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
        if (today <= dayINeed) { 
        // then just give me this week's instance of that day
        return moment().isoWeekday(dayINeed);
        } else {
         // otherwise, give me *next week's* instance of that same day
        return moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed);
        }
    };

    const getCountdown = (ending) =>
    {
        var now = moment();
var end = moment(ending); // another date
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));

//Get Days and subtract from duration
var days = duration.asDays();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(days,'days'));

//Get hours and subtract from duration
var hours = duration.hours();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(hours,'hours'));

//Get Minutes and subtract from duration
var minutes = duration.minutes();
duration.subtract(moment.duration(minutes,'minutes'));

//Get seconds
var seconds = duration.seconds();
console.log("Days: ",days);
console.log("Hours: ",hours);
console.log("Minutes: ",minutes);
console.log("Seconds: ",seconds);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're using `asDays()` which converts your duration to a decimal number (including hours, minutes, and seconds in decimal part)

And you don't need to call `moment.duration(x,'x')` in every subtraction

The fix should be

```
const getCountdown = (ending) => {
  var now = moment();
  var end = moment(ending); // another date
  var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));

  //Get Days and subtract from duration
  var days = duration.days();
  duration.subtract(days, 'days');

  //Get hours and subtract from duration
  var hours = duration.hours();
  duration.subtract(hours, 'hours');

  //Get Minutes and subtract from duration
  var minutes = duration.minutes();
  duration.subtract(minutes, 'minutes');

  //Get seconds
  var seconds = duration.seconds();
  console.log("Days: ", days);
  console.log("Hours: ", hours);
  console.log("Minutes: ", minutes);
  console.log("Seconds: ", seconds);
};
```

Comment: Hello, now days and hours show up correctly but minutes and seconds always show as 59

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6dvLmrx4/ Could you check here? I modified some data to test it. The code seems working fine for me. @gabogabans

Comment: Hi, I copied you code but minutes and seconds still show up at 59 and 59, always...

Comment: I know why it's happening to you. You have the logic to handle `dayINeed`, and it never goes through the sample data I set up earlier. You can try this again https://jsfiddle.net/j0d637ot/2/. Note that I just removed `dayINeed` logic for testing, you can add it back in your logic @gabogabans

Comment: still getting the same result